# Remove default selection row Datagrid View

Tags: datagrid

In `DataGridView` there is a row selected and highlighted by default. How can this default selection and highlighting be removed?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I figured it out myself.

After populating the `DataGrid`, I called the following method:

```
datagrid.ClearSelection();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that [faking the prevention of selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745272/disable-cell-highlighting-in-a-datagridview#1745295) worked better for me.

See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330147/how-to-disable-datagridview-select-ability#16818991) for a more thorough solution.