# Datagrid selected row highlighted

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a DataGrid with four columns that will have a control in each column for each row. Whenever I select one of the controls in a column whichever row it belongs to gets highlighted white. The background will be white so the controls still show. I don't want the row to highlight at all.

```
<DataGrid>
<DataGrid.Columns>                                                                 
    <DataGridTemplateColumn>                                                                                                         
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>                                                                                                                    
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn >
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223280/how-can-i-set-the-color-of-a-selected-row-in-datagrid

Comment: The suggestions there help abit. I am able now when I am selected on the row some of the white is covered up. Some still shows and after I click off the datagrid the row that was most recently selected still has this white highlighting in it.

Comment: Have you tried styling the `DataGrid` using its `CellStyle`?

Comment: Ive tried, CellStyle, RowStyle, ColumnStyle, a bunch with the IsSelected Trigger settings the border and background and nothing seems to get rid of it.

Comment: the second answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745272/disable-cell-highlighting-in-a-datagridview) might help

Comment: That seems to be for a datagridview I'm using a DataGrid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override `HighlightBrushKey` for your DataGrid but in case you set that to white, highlighted text also corresponds to white color so that won't be visible.

So, basically you need to override `HighlightBrushKey` to `White` and `HighlightTextBrushKey` to `Black` to make it work. This is how you override it -

```
<DataGrid>
  <DataGrid.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"
                     Color="White"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}"
                     Color="Black"/>
  </DataGrid.Resources>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<DataGrid SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="Cell"
```

Comment: That seems to work good except that only the column with the control that you selected now has the white highlighting rather than the whole row.