# How can i totally disable tabbing on DataGridView but keep ability to select rows?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, tabindex, tab-ordering

How can I totally disable tabbing on DataGridView so it won't go through cells at all?

I use DataGridView as music playlist in my application and I don't need that annoying windows default selection frame around cells. I want be able to select rows normally. I managed to hide selection border on buttons with SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, false) but this does not disable tabbing on DataGridView.

Comment: It's really too much code. I'll post a [PICTURE](http://kenny.republika.pl/1.png)

Comment: Is the picture just to show us your taste in music? Yes, I like Eminem, too. But that doesn't get us any closer to debugging your problem.

Comment: See also: [Disable Cell Highlighting in a datagridview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745272/disable-cell-highlighting-in-a-datagridview)

Comment: I posted picture to show you the selection frame i wanted to get rid of. By the way, this is totally different problem than the one above, read carefully man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I've managed to do that. This [ARTICLE](http://geekswithblogs.net/aghausman/archive/2009/04/26/disable-special-keys-in-win-app-c.aspx) helped me a lot. I used form's OnActivated and OnDeactivated events to disable and enable TAB key. Here you have sample code:

```
protected override void OnActivated(EventArgs e) {

    ProcessModule objCurrentModule = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule;
    objKeyboardProcess = new LowLevelKeyboardProc(captureKey);
    ptrHook = SetWindowsHookEx(13, objKeyboardProcess, GetModuleHandle(objCurrentModule.ModuleName), 0);

    base.OnActivated(e);
}

protected override void OnDeactivate(EventArgs e) {

    UnhookWindowsHookEx(ptrHook);
    objKeyboardProcess = null;
    ptrHook = IntPtr.Zero;

    base.OnDeactivate(e);
}
```

There were a couple of problems that came up while i was trying to make it work but that's different story. Happy coding! :)

Comment: That article needs a caveat: **hooks are not the solution to your programming problem**.

Answer (score 5):

Handle the KeyDown event of the DataGridView and call the parent (or grandparent) control's [SelectNextControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.selectnextcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyDown( object sender, KeyEventArgs e )
{
    if ( e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab )
    {
        SelectNextControl( dataGridView1, true, true, true, true );
        // or Parent.SelectNextControl() if the grid is an only child, etc.
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

This will cause the whole grid to behave like tabbing among text boxes and buttons - you tab into the grid, and another press of the tab key will tab out and onto the next control. This retains navigation within the grid by the cursor keys. Refer to the linked MSDN documentation for options on the direction of tabbing, etc., which are what all those terrible Boolean parameters configure. The first parameter sets which control the "next" tab search begins from, so you can set that to a parent or sibling or grandparent.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to DataGrid don't focus, you can set it's `Enable` property to false, this control on the form doesn't get focus, but in this way you must add or delete rows in DataGridView with specific button (it means a button for add and another for delete)

but if you want their cells don't focus, you should following this: in `KeyDown` event of your `form`, type this code

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab)
    {
         dgvMain.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
         [other component of your form like a textbox or a button].Focus();
    }
```

with this, your DataGridView only highlight the whole selected row

Comment: Hmmm, the thing is i still need to be able to select rows. I have fullRowSelect turned on and i have some hidden cells. There is 6 cells in every row but only 3 of them are visible. This is music playlist and i want rows to be selected and change color. That's not the thing. What i don't like is the windows default border around every cell showing when you press Tab key, i want to disable this frame and prevent user from going through list with tab key.

Comment: so disable the whole DataGrid, it has a property named `Enable`, you can either visualize and coding change it's value, set it false, so you can't select DataGrid anymore

Comment: you don't get me, if i set Enable to false on DataGridView i won't be able to select anything at all, it's not what i'm looking for

Comment: I think i get it ;). click DataGrid and click on `DefaultCellStyle` property, and a window will be shown, so you set set `BackColor` and `SelectionBackColor` to the same color, and set `ForeColor` and `SelectionForeColor` to the same color, too. I think it's your problem that I wish it helps you :)

Comment: you should do something which selected and non-selected row be the same, and the difference between selected and non-selected one, is just the color, I kill myself if it doesn't work buddy ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can also set:

```
dataGridView.TabStop=false;
```

This will skip the grid when the tab button is hit.